# Constante local a global

Tags: reactjs

Necesito acceder a una constante (idNumber) que esta dentro de una funcion  y pasarla al scope global porque la necesito usar en otros lados, y esa constante toma un valor que solo puede ser pasado por un parametro dentro de la misma funcion.

Por otro lado, no puedo invocar a la funcion "handleEdit" asi porque si, porque como veran, se ejecuta otra funcion dentro.

Solo necesito "quitar" ese valor y ponerlo en el scope global. Gracias desde ya!

PD: Estoy trabajando con React

Este es mi codigo

```
const handleEdit = function (id) {
{setEditState (!editState)}
const idNumber = id
}
```

Comment: ¿Estás usando la sintaxis Class para los componentes de tu proyecto? ¿En que nivel se encuentra 'handleEdit' dentro del árbol jerárquico de componentes? Es decir que tan lejos del Parent component.

Comment: Para eso justamente son los estados. O si lo ocupas desde un nivel superior, para eso existe el contexto (`useContext`) o utilerías como `redux`. Define mejor qué es lo que quieres para obtener ayuda.